# Potential PHP problems with EE 1.13 or CE 1.8

Tags: php, ee-1.13, magento-enterprise

My client is on an old server running PHP 5.2.17, should I encourage him to upgrade to 5.3 or will it be ok?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The support for PHP 5.2 [ended in August 2011](https://www.php.net/archive/2011.php#id2011-08-23-1), so I recommend to update the PHP installation.
The [configuration site on magentocommerce.com](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/ce18-and-ee113-installing) shows that PHP 5.3 is required.

Some weeks ago we had some issues with a PHP 5.4 installation, EE 1.12 and atomic repo (<del>some segmentation faults</del>) and we stepped back to 5.3.

Update: The error was

> Fatal error: Cannot override final method
> Mage_Core_Model_Abstract::clearInstance() in various PHP-Files

with PHP 5.4.17

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to try with PHP 5.4. If it is EE installation please talk to support first as 5.4 is not officially supported yet (not fully tested) but works correctly since 1.13/1.8 based on the feedback i got.

Comment: In my experience it seems to work - but there are reports / documented SimpleXML bugs regarding how Magento makes use of simplexml objects returning a custom class name/type.

Comment: We have also had issues with php 5.4 a while back, and downgraded to 5.3, thus suggest to go with 5.3